# Ordering the n-1 nearest neighbours for each of n data points

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

Assume we have n data points in a dataset. For a given point, we can order each of the n-1 other points based on its (metric) distance to that point.

What is the most efficient way to calculate this for every point in the dataset given we have a metric distance function such as an L-norm?

The naive approach seems to be to sort the list of distances for each point in turn, at a cost of O(n log n) per point, i.e. O(n^2 log n) for all points. Using a k-d tree seems no better given the full tree must be traversed each time.

Is there a better way that can take advantage of the triangle inequality, for example?

Comment: I think you are getting it correctly. O(n^2 log n). But if i understood it correctly, cant simple BST be used here?

Comment: Perhaps O(n^2 log n)  is not too high cost for getting sequences containing n^2 items

Answer (score 0):

Since your output is O(n^2) you will not be able to get better than that.

I think this boils down to how fast you can rank all other points with respect to the distance to a point q. If you have an index structure (e.g., a KD-Tree or an R-Tree) you can use [distance browsing](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.386.8193&rep=rep1&type=pdf) to sort all other points w.r.t. q.

The basic idea of distance browsing is to have a priority queue pq whose entries are sorted by minimum distance to q. pq can contain points and entries of the index structure. You start with putting the root entry of the index structure into pq. Then you start poping elements from pq. When you encounter an entry (node) you resolve it and put the children back in to pq. When you encounter a point then you found your next nearest neighbour of q.

Overall an index structure has O(n) entries. Poping an element from pq is O(log |pq|). This makes the runtime O(n * log |pq|). The question is how many elements will be in pq in average.

I don't have a proof for this but a quick sketch let's me assume that the average number of elements in the queue should be around O(sqrt(n)) for L_1 and 2D space. Note, that the size of the queue heavily depends on the distance metric and the dimension of your points.

Putting all this together you can build the index structure (O(n log n)) and then for each point q rank all other points (O(n * log(sqrt(n))))

Overall this gives you a runtime of `O(n * log(n) + n^2 * log(sqrt(n)))`.

However, to echo @MBo: this is a large hassle for little improvement over O(n^2 * log (n))

Comment: `n^2 * log(sqrt(n))` is not an improvement over `n^2 * log(n)`, especially after taking into account the increased constant of proportionality. Also can you provide some more justification for the square root? Looks impressive though.

Comment: Welp, you are right. Regarding the square root: All entries close to the current search radius are in the pq. All other entries are either already resolved or cover very large areas and are neglected in my estimation. So you look at the ratio of the search radius (circumfence) with some width epsilon to the whole space.